# CUPS asking for root password to resume printer on KDE

Tags: password, root, printing, cups, printer

How can I configure CUPS not to ask for root password to resume or add a printer? Or add users so they're "administrators"? When using KDE Plasma, it asks for root password: "please enter a username and a password" and it has root in the username field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Arch Linux at least, the proper place to fix this issue is in the file:

```
/etc/cups/cups-files.conf
```

The above file (instead of `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`) will contain the `SystemGroup` setting. (That's probably why @simplegamer  couldn't find it in the file mentioned in the other answer here.)

The standard way to resolve this issue in Arch Linux is to:

First add the "sys" group to `SystemGroup` in `/etc/cups/cups-files.conf` . Here is an example:

```
# Administrator user group, used to match @SYSTEM in cupsd.conf policy rules...
# This cannot contain the Group value for security reasons...
SystemGroup sys wheel
```

Second, add the user to the "sys" group:

```
gpasswd -a your_username sys
```

Log out, if logged in as that user for the group change to take effect. After logging in as that user run `groups` to check that the user belongs to the "sys" group. Now the user should be able to manage printers without being asked for a password.

This approach allows users without sudo rights to be able to manage printers, which is the right approach in my situation. We do not have a root account enabled and we have users who should not have sudo rights, but these users should be able to manage printers / printing.

Beware of solutions suggesting that you "set a root password" in Ubuntu.

printing - "Adding Printer" dialog asks for root password? - Ask Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/20318/adding-printer-dialog-asks-for-root-password

This is related:

Bug #653132 ""Add Printer” dialog requests root password if user... : Bugs : system-config-printer package : Ubuntu https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/653132

Answer (score 1):

Add a `group` which contains the normal users that should have access to `cups administration` in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` below the `# Administrator user group...` line.

```
SystemGroup sys root users
```

Then add the normal user's to the group `users`

Restart the service, and you should be good to go.

```
systemctl restart cupsd.service
```

Comment: `users` in the configuration and `user` as the actual group? they have different names, I don't think it would work but I'll try it with the same name

Comment: @simplegamer Sorry a typo I edited it. use `users`

Comment: There's no `# Administrator user group...` in my cupsd.conf, so I just added it to the top